# Grails - Full Page Caching

Tags: caching, grails, grails-cache

I'm putting up a small website where only one page needs information from a database, and the rest of the pages are static. How can I implement full page caching for those static pages while still using the default fragmented cache system for the one page that needs it? I would prefer to use the same sitemesh layout for all the pages if I can. The sitemesh layout only contains static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<cache:block>` [tag](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/ref/Tags/block.html) of the [cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) (installed in Grails 2.X apps by default) to cache all or part of the static pages. Here's how you would use it to cache the entire page

```
<cache:block>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>my static page</body>
</html>

</cache:block>
```

Even without using this plugin, I'm pretty sure there is already a caching mechanism for GSP rendering (in the production environment) so I doubt you'll see a big performance gain.

If these static pages require execution a controller action (rather than just rendering a view), you can cache that too using the `@Cacheable` [annotation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html#annotations) provided by the cache plugin